# Migrating local Docker images to buildx

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have been using several locally built docker images that I am trying to migrate to building with `docker buildx`. Essentially I have a local container to build something from source, and then a prod container that references the local build container.

For example, I have two Dockerfiles in a directory, `Dockerfile.builder` and `Dockerfile.prod`

```
# Dockerfile.builder
FROM maven:3-eclipse-temurin-17
ARG VERSION

# clone git repository, do building things
```

```
# Dockerfile.prod
ARG BUILDER_TAG
FROM builder:$BUILDER_TAG as builder
# pull in build artifacts from builder container, do other things
```

Then from that working directory I would build the containers like so:

```
docker build --no-cache --build-arg VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION -t builder-container:${BUILD_VERSION} -f Dockerfile.builder .

docker build --no-cache --build-arg BUILDER_TAG=$BUILD_VERSION -t prod-container:${BUILD_VERSION} -f Dockerfile.prod .
```

I'm trying to adapt this to `docker buildx` but am struggling with the extra overhead and complexity.

I think this would be the closest to what I'm wanting to do:

```
docker buildx build --no-cache --build-arg VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION -t builder:${BUILD_VERSION} - < Dockerfile.builder
```

However, when I try that, I get the following:

```
[+] Building 4.3s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                               
 => ERROR [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                   4.0s
 => => transferring context:                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                4.3s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 30B                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
------
 > [internal] load .dockerignore:
------
------
 > [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile:
------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: failed to remove: /var/lib/docker/zfs/graph/hiqgpytehhglat0nn1a06dop1/.zfs: unlinkat /var/lib/docker/zfs/graph/hiqgpytehhglat0nn1a06dop1/.zfs/snapshot: operation not permitted
```

So that is telling me that it's not reading from my Dockerfile that I'm trying to supply via STDIN, and the path `/var/lib/docker/zfs/graph/hiqgpytehhglat0nn1a06dop1/.zfs/snapshot` doesn't exist.

Am I invoking `docker buildx` correctly for my use case?

Do I need to start with a fresh graph directory in order to start building my own images with `buildx`, or is there something I need to do with `docker buildx create` first?

I'm finding Docker's documentation on `buildx` very lacking in terms of how it differs conceptually from the legacy `docker build`, and I think that's part of my problem.

buildx config:

```
docker buildx inspect
Name:          default
Driver:        docker
Last Activity: 2023-02-15 03:27:29 +0000 UTC

Nodes:
Name:      default
Endpoint:  default
Status:    running
Buildkit:  23.0.1
Platforms: linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2, linux/amd64/v3, linux/386
```

Answer (score 0):

`docker buildx build` supports the same flags as `docker build`( https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/buildx_build/)

You should be able to use the `-f` flag as before:

```
docker buildx build --no-cache --build-arg VERSION=$BUILD_VERSION -t builder-container:${BUILD_VERSION} -f Dockerfile.builder .
```